# Does std::list variable in the class need initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization

I have recently read something like this. I konw it is not so complex. But as a beginner, I just don't know why it works, so here is the description.

```cpp
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
 
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    list<T *> testlist;
    A();
    ~A();
    void m_append(T* one);
};

template <typename T>
A<T>::A()
{
    cout << "constructor" << endl;
}

template <typename T>
A<T>::~A()
{
    cout << "destructor" << endl;
}

template <typename T>
void A<T>::m_append(T* one)
{
    cout << *one << " push in" << endl;
    testlist.push_back(one);
}

int main(void)
{
    A<int> a;
    int b = 4;
    int c = 5;
    int d = 6;
    a.m_append(&b);
    a.m_append(&c);
    a.m_append(&d);

    return 0;
}
```

In my opinion this **testlist** is not initialized, there should be something wrong.

But it works.

```
constructor
4 push in
4
5 push in
5
6 push in
6
destructor
```

So I am pretty confused. There is no need to initialize this **testlist** or?

Comment: As long as std::list<> has a default constructor (which it does), it will be initialized by the call to A::A() (as an empty list). As an aside, putting raw pointers into a list is fraught with pitfalls. For the next iteration perhaps consider using std::unique_ptr, or std::shared_ptr instead, as they will look after the tidy up for you.

Comment: OK. Thanks for that advice. I'll go have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data member `testlist` is not mentioned in the member initializer list of constructor of `A`, and doesn't have default member initializer (since C++11), then it would be [default initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) via the default constructor of `std::list`.

> 3. when a base class or a non-static data member is not mentioned in a constructor initializer list and that constructor is called.

And

> There is no need to initialize this testlist or?

It depends on your intent. If the default initialization is enough, then yes.

Answer (score -2):

To understand this, you must know how a list is constructed.
It has a control block on the stack and then allocates elements on the heap if you insert elements. The control block is initialized by the constructor.

Here is a picture to understand how this looks like:

[image]

So you don't need to initialize the list.

Comment: The questions seems more like 'why is the constructor called', not 'why is a default-constructed list ok to use'.

Comment: The question isn't really about how std::list<> uses memory. It is more that the list gets initialized without an explicit entry in the A constructor initalizer list, because list<> has a default constructor. The OP is concerned about uninitialized variables, which is a good thing!

Comment: The "controllblock" is for most implementations of the std enclosed within the `std::list` type. If the list is created on the stack then the controllblock would then be on the stack. But the type could also be initialized on the heap, and then it would be on the heap. Whether list nodes are allocated on the stack or on the heap depends on the allocator, the default allocator for most std implementation will allocate the elements on the heap. Using the terms stack and heap is in many cases inaccurate and not required. Storage duration and lifetime are often better choices.